# AttributeError: module 'sklearn.feature_extraction.image' has no attribute 'extract_patches'

Tags: python, sklearn-pandas

AttributeError: module 'sklearn.feature_extraction.image' has no attribute 'extract_patches'

How to solve it without patchify.

Comment: try with `extract_patches_2d`

Answer (score 0):

`extract_patches_2d` and `reconstruct_from_patches_2d` are the current methods which can be used in the sklearn image feature_extraction library. Try one of those and see if it works. Source here: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f3f51f9b6/sklearn/feature_extraction/image.py#L323